# React sending list-select data not working with formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm using formik to send form data over to my API and some of the form data are selectable dropdowns, i'm using headless ui's `Listbox` component to render the options

```
  const Region = [
        { id: 'ADDISABEBA', name: 'Addis abeba' },
        { id: 'MEAKELAYTIGRAY', name: 'Meakelay tigray' },
        { id: 'MEBRAKTIGRAY', name: 'Mebrak tigray' },
   ]
    export default function CreateSchool() {
    const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState(Region[0])
    //const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState(Type[0])
    //const [email, setEmail] = useState([])
    //const [password, setPassword] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const onSubmit = async (values) => {
        console.log(values)
        setIsLoading(true)
        try {
            let res = await axiosInstance.post(`schools/create/`, values)
            if(res.status === 200 && res.statusText === "OK"){
               navigate('/app/schools', { replace: true })
               setIsLoading(false)
             }
            console.log(res.data);
            
        } catch (err) {
            //setEmail(err.response.data.error);
            //setPassword(err.response.data.error);
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    };

  const formik = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
          ...
          zone: selectedRegion.id,
          ...
       },
      validateOnBlur: true,
      onSubmit,
      validationSchema: CreateSchoolValidationSchema,
  })
  console.log('region', selectedRegion.id)
   ...
   }
```

**the Listbox component:-**

```
            <Listbox value={selectedType} onChange={setSelectedType} className="my-2 w-72">
                <div className="relative mt-1">
                    <Listbox.Button className="relative w-72 py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left bg-Bgdark rounded-lg shadow-sm cursor-default focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                        <span className="block truncate">{selectedType.name}</span>
                        <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none">
                            <svg className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M8 9l4-4 4 4m0 6l-4 4-4-4" />
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </Listbox.Button>
                    <Transition
                        as={Fragment}
                        enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    >
                        <Listbox.Options className="absolute origin-top w-72 py-1 mt-1 overflow-auto text-base bg-Bgdark rounded-md shadow-lg max-h-60 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
                            {Type.map((Schooltype) => (
                                <Listbox.Option
                                    value={Schooltype}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    key={Schooltype.id}
                                    id="Schooltype"
                                    name="Schooltype"
                                    className={({ active }) =>
                                        `${active ? 'text-white bg-Btncolor' : 'text-gray-200'}
                          cursor-default select-none relative py-2 pl-10 pr-4`
                                    }
                                >
                                    {({ selected, active }) => (
                                        <>
                                            <span
                                                className={`${selected ? 'font-medium' : 'font-normal'
                                                    } block truncate`}
                                            >
                                                {Schooltype.name}
                                            </span>
                                            {selected ? (
                                                <span
                                                    className={`${active ? 'text-white' : 'text-white'
                                                        }
                                absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3`}
                                                >
                                                    <svg className="w-5 h-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M5 13l4 4L19 7" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                </span>
                                            ) : null}
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                </Listbox.Option>
                            ))}
                        </Listbox.Options>
                    </Transition>
                </div>
            </Listbox>
```

since the Listbox component saves the selected option in state to display it, I pointed to the state in formik's initialvalues, but when I see the dev tools net tab the payload being sent is always the first option and not the selected one

Comment: what does your `Type` array look like?

Comment: it is the same as the Region one, if i can solve the region one the type is the same so i can fix that to.

Answer (score 1):

well since you are using formik's submitted values,
you should be using formik's builtin change handlers instead of setting an independent state(like in your example below)
[image]

the other workaround you can do is to use an effect to somehow alter formik's value(only do this if you have really no choice)

Comment: how do i do the earlier recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Listbox value={selectedType} onChange={setSelectedType} className="my-2 w-72">
            <div className="relative mt-1">
                <Listbox.Button className="relative w-72 py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left bg-Bgdark rounded-lg shadow-sm cursor-default focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                    <span className="block truncate">{selectedType.name}</span>
                    <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none">
                        <svg className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M8 9l4-4 4 4m0 6l-4 4-4-4" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </Listbox.Button>
                <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                    enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                    leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                >
                    <Listbox.Options className="absolute origin-top w-72 py-1 mt-1 overflow-auto text-base bg-Bgdark rounded-md shadow-lg max-h-60 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
                        {Type.map((Schooltype) => (
                            <Listbox.Option
                                value={Schooltype}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                key={Schooltype.id}
                                id="Schooltype"
                                name="Schooltype"
                                className={({ active }) =>
                                    `${active ? 'text-white bg-Btncolor' : 'text-gray-200'}
                      cursor-default select-none relative py-2 pl-10 pr-4`
                                }
                            >
                                {({ selected, active }) => (
                                    <>
                                        <span
                                            className={`${selected ? 'font-medium' : 'font-normal'
                                                } block truncate`}
                                        >
                                            {Schooltype.name}
                                        </span>
                                        {selected ? (
                                            <span
                                                className={`${active ? 'text-white' : 'text-white'
                                                    }
                            absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3`}
                                            >
                                                <svg className="w-5 h-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M5 13l4 4L19 7" />
                                                </svg>
                                            </span>
                                        ) : null}
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </Listbox.Option>
                        ))}
                    </Listbox.Options>
                </Transition>
            </div>
        </Listbox>
```

Thanks

Comment: this does not work